# Set Select Dropdown with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question has been asked multiple times, but this is not a repeat. I am using a for loop to search through a div of elements including select, input etc. It matches the class name to an objects parameter and if it matches it sets the value of the element.

```
for(var i in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        $(editClone).find('.' +i).val(obj[i]);
    }
}
```

It works fine on input elements, but with the select element it removes all the options and simply sets the value on the actual element tag.

This is the select statement before I run my javascript:

```
<select class="type">
    <option value="Home">Home</option>
    <option value="Work">Work</option>
    <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

And after I run the code (inspected in firebug to verify):

```
<select class="type">Mobile</select>
```

Why does it do this? I thought val() was supposed to set a matching option tag to selected. The object value and option tags are matching, but it does not do what it is supposed to. What am I doing wrong here?

**Turns out I had the DIV I was trying to clone nested in the wrong place in the HTML as well as a bad clone call in the javascript. Totally unrelated errors. The answer below is correct, it just didn't work in my situation because I didn't understand the problem I was having.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select class="type">Mobile</select>
```

Is not valid.  A select needs to have `option` tags inside of it

---

Here's a working version of your code:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hay9G/)

```
<select class="type">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
</select>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {

    var obj = { type: "A" };

    var editClone = $(document);

    for(var i in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            $(editClone).find('.' + i).val(obj[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I wish I could say that worked, but thats exactly what I already have. I just didn't include the object and editClone in my sample code because it was irrelevant. For some reason val() is replacing the html() inside the select statement as opposed to choosing the option and selecting the matching one.

Comment: The select class, does originally have options, and Mobile is one of the choices. The javascript replaces all the options with Mobile.

Comment: @ryandlf - it's not replacing any html.  It's just setting the A option to be selected, just like you want.  Inspect the html in chrome dev tools or firebug to see for yourself :)

Comment: I use firebug, and it is replacing the HTML! Weird, I know. It starts with a regular select statement with options, and then after that JS runs, it replaces all the options with the string I am trying to match with one of the options. I'll edit my answer with both select elements, before and after.

Comment: @ryandlf if this solution isn't working for you, then please post a jsfiddle that shows the issue you are having.